# Imprimir variable de un método desde un módulo

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Hola agradecería si alguien sabe como imprimir variables que pertenecen a un método que se encuentra en un modulo. Les dejo uno de mis infructíferos intentos.

```
#Este es el código del módulo
import MySQLdb


def Consultar():

    vCodigo = "BC1"

    try:
        db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "1234", "pcsolution")
        cursor=db.cursor()
        sql = ("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE Codigo='"+vCodigo+"'; ")
        cursor.execute(sql)
        for (Codigo, Producto, Marca, Detalles, Costo, Precio, Descuento, Unidades) in cursor:

            global vMarca
            global vProducto
            global vPrecio
            vMarca    = Marca
            vProducto = Producto
            vPrecio   = Precio



            db.commit()
            db.close()

    except:

        print ("Error en la conexion")








#Código principal

import moduloPizarron


moduloPizarron.Consultar()

print (vProducto)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando realizas un import de la  forma:

```
import moduloPizarron
```

No cargas en el espacio de nombres actual las variables globales del módulo. Para acceder a ellas necesitas indicar el name-space adecuado como haces cuando llamas a la función:

```
print (moduloPizarron.vProducto)
```

Un ejemplo simple:

```
# miModulo.py

def foo():
    global n
    n = 4
```

---

```
>>> import myModulo
>>> myModulo.foo()
>>> print(myModulo.n)
4
```

No es por lo general la forma más apropiada de hacerlo. Una forma más robusta y legible sería hacer que la función retorne lo que quieras:

```
# miModulo.py

def foo():
    n = 4
    return n
```

---

```
>>> import miModulo
>>> n = miModulo.foo()
>>> print(n)
4
```

Otra opción sería hacerlo desde la perspectiva de la programación orientada a objetos y acceder a sus atributos:

```
# miModulo.py

class MiClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = o

    def foo(self):
        self.n = 4
```

---

```
>>> import miModulo
>>> inst = miModulo.MiClass()
>>> inst.foo()
>>> print(inst.n)
4
```

Dado que tu función `Consultar` hace una consulta y es de suponer que retorna diferentes filas de la tabla, deberías hacer que retorne por ejemplo una lista (o cualquier iterable) con las filas que tu consulta retorna y iterar sobre ella en tu módulo principal. Tal y como lo hace solo vas a obtener el último resultado del query ya que cada ciclo del `for` sobreescribe la variable de turno.

Comment: Problema solucionado. Lo hago de esta forma porque quiero cargar mas de una variable, con "return" solo puedo cargar una.

Comment: @Samuel si quieres se pueden enviar lo que quieres con `return` (cualquier numero de variables o cualquier objeto) . Por ejemplo: `a = 3`, `b=4`, `c = 5`;  `return a, b, c` es valido. Esto retorna una tupla que puedes desempaquetar luego con `a, b, c = foo()`. Un saludo.